# MongoDB: Using $setWindowFields after $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have ~30,000 instances, each with a given timestamp and continent.

I'd like to run a query that groups the data by month, returns a count of instances for each defined continent (e.g. "Europe", "Asia") per month, and then calculates the cumulative count for each continent.

The query is for a Grafana dashboard so it needs to be an aggregation operation.

At the moment, my query returns the continent count of the given row, rather than a cumulative count of the row and preceding rows.

E.g. If Europe is "10" at time "2020-02-01 0:00:00", then cumulativeCount will also be "10", regardless of what came before.

Query:

```
targets.targets.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "status.isError": false,
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-01T00:00:00.000Z", date: { $toDate: "$date_posted" }
                }
            },
            Europe: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$continent", "Europe"] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            Europe: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "_id": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            time: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$_id" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            time: 1,
            Europe: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $setWindowFields: {
            partitionBy: "$time",
            sortBy: { "time": 1 },
            output: {
                cumulativeCount: {
                    $sum: "$Europe"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

If I try to $setWindowFields before grouping, the query errors because the sort exceeds the memory limit.

Comment: Have you tried using [allowDiskUse](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.allowDiskUse/)?

Comment: Remove the `partitionBy: "$time"` inside the `$setWindowFields`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"status.isError": false}},
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        date: {
          $dateTrunc: {
            date: "$date_posted",
            unit: "day"
          }
        },
        continent: "$continent"
      },
      count: {$sum: 1}
  }},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      continent: "$_id.continent",
      date: "$_id.date",
      count: 1
  }},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$continent",
      sortBy: {"date": 1},
      output: {
        cumulativeCount: {
          $sum: "$count",
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qXj3cFxNRGK)

Comment: Incredibly helpful. Thank you :-)